# How to convert an existing emberJS web app to a Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js

I have my `emberJS` web app , and I would like to make a mobile app `(Android/IOS)` from it? Is this possible?

Is is possible to make a `cordova` project out of it.Please put some thoughts..

Comment: I dont know why negative voting its new topic.if you dont  understand please ask me

Comment: I have not down voted the question. But one probable reason for down vote may be that it does not comply to things mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Its always adviced to show the problem and ask for solution rather than asking for implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the step we should follow

```
npm install -g ember-cli
ember install ember-cli-cordova
ember generate cordova-init com.someproject.name
ember cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

This talk from this years Ember conf can help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry639hvWKbM